# Tomcat 5.5 won't start in eclipse - Timeout after 5 minutes

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, timeout

My tomcat 5.5 start fine when I start it by itself. When I try to start it in eclipse, it times out. It just sits at "Starting Tomcat v5.5...at localhost". I even changed the timeout to 5 minutes and it still won't start. I've tried reinstalling my tomcat in eclipse multiple times and that hasn't helped at all. Please help.

Comment: Eclipse and jdk version?  It might matter.

Comment: I'm actually using Rad 7.5 which is built on eclipse 3.4 I'm using jdk 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of messing with this, I finally figured out that it was a specific project that I had added to the server. It somehow caused the server to never start. When I switched the jdk from the workbench default, to version 6 which I downloaded, it worked fine. I'm still not exactly sure if there is a jar in that project that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the timeout in the server configuration screen in Eclipse which you can get by doubleclicking the server entry in the *Servers* view. You could try to increase it to 100 seconds or something. But I don't think that this will fix the real problem.

You need to ensure that Tomcat which is started externally is completely shutdown before you start it from inside Eclipse. To verify this, go in your webbrowser to the address where Tomcat should be listening on, e.g. http://localhost:8080. If you get a browser default connection timeout error, then it's fine. This way you should be able to start it from inside Eclipse.

If in vain, you could try to clean the Tomcat working directory by rightclicking the server entry and choosing *Clean*. If still in vain, try restarting Eclipse as `eclipse.exe -clean`.

Comment: I had set the timeout to 5 minutes and that didn't help. I tried the url http://localhost:8080 and it gave a page error. I cleaned the tomcat working directory and that didn't help either.

Comment: Please be more specific with "a page error". What exactly? The browser default connection timeout error? For example [this Firefox one](http://www.travelinlibrarian.info/uploaded_images/1.5error-747918.png) (which means that server is indeed shutdown) or do you see for example a [Tomcat-default HTTP 404 error page](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/5042/tomcat404.png) (which means that Tomcat is actually still running)?

Comment: It's not a tomcat error. In google chrome it's an "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080" error.

Comment: Did you try restarting Eclipse with `-clean` argument?

Comment: If I type in "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\eclipse.exe" in the command prompt it loads eclipse, if I try it with -clean like this "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\eclipse.exe -clean", it gives an error that windows cannot find "C:\Program".

Comment: The quotes should only go around the path `"C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\eclipse.exe" -clean`,

Comment: Ok that was it, but tomcat still doesn't start.

Comment: Bummer. Probably Tomcat itself is totally messed up or the Eclipse server plugin is totally messed up. Maybe you modified (unawarely) a bit too much. I'd first try to restart the entire PC. If in vain, I'd try to download and/or extract a fresh new Tomcat zip file from http://tomcat.apache.org and then integrate this one in Eclipse. If in vain, I'd try to download and/or extract a fresh new Eclipse zip file from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1 and try this one.

Comment: I've tried restarting, re-downloading tomcat, and I can't download a fresh copy of eclipse because the corporate standard is Rad. I guess the last thing to try is to re-install Rad. I'll let you know if that helps.

Comment: Oh you're using RAD, sorry I overlooked that. By the way, did you try to start Tomcat without any projects deployed? Has it worked from inside RAD before?

Comment: It hasn't worked inside RAD on my new machine. My old one did just fine. Yes I was trying to start Tomcat without any projects deployed.

Comment: What OS? Did you ever get firewall warnings which you (accidently) blocked? It might be the cause as well. Check the firewall settings.

Comment: Windows XP. I don't think I have control to the firewall. Pretty sure that's on lock down.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but I had the same problem when I updated to eclipse indigo and the problem was fixed when I changed JDK version to 1.6.0_36.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (kepler) switching between jdks didn't work, but putting just one webapp at a time (when debugging) did the trick.